Is it illegal to use a fake state ID to enter a private establishment even when a legitimate ID would've been fine?
Fake IDs are normally used by people whose genuine IDs would be rejected (e.g., minors entering a bar), but this made me wonder:
What happens if you carry around & use a fake state ID (plain ID, NOT a fake driver's license) when you aren't otherwise breaking any rules, and when your normal ID would've been accepted just fine?
One motivation for this might for privacy purposes, because a genuine IDs often contains personal information that really isn't the establishment's business, such as your home address, weight, organ-donation status, ID number, etc.
Is carrying around & using an ID solely for such purposes illegal?

The 9/11 terrorists carried forged documents in their real names. I don’t think I ever found out why.

A similar case would be counterfeit currency, which is also more likely to draw law enforcement attention.  Rush Hour 2's prop maker received an angry visit from the secret service over this.

@Brian: was it just an angry visit or was what they were doing actually illegal?

@user541686: The government reaction was prompted by crew members taking the money and spending it, which is definitely illegal.  The prop company itself were accused of counterfeiting money and forced to destroy a bunch of money that was set to be used in other movies.  They were also slapped with a cease-and-desist order.  Had they decided to be obstructionist, I'm sure the secret service would have happily fought them in court.

united-states washington
It is illegal to create or use an unauthorized identification card for any purpose. Specifically, RCW 46.20.0921 provides that:

(1) It is a misdemeanor for any person:

(a) To display or cause or permit to be displayed or have in his or her possession any fictitious or fraudulently altered driver's license or identicard;
(c) To display or represent as one's own any driver's license or identicard not issued to him or her;

(3) It is unlawful for any person to manufacture, sell, or deliver a forged, fictitious, counterfeit, fraudulently altered, or unlawfully issued driver's license or identicard.... A violation of this subsection is:

(a) A class C felony if committed (i) for financial gain or (ii) with intent to commit forgery, theft, or identity theft; or
(b) A gross misdemeanor if the conduct does not violate (a) of this subsection.


The purpose is only relevant to the question of whether it's a felony or not. If not used for theft or other financial gain, the question will be whether it's considered forgery under RCW 9A.60.020:

(1) A person is guilty of forgery if, with intent to injure or defraud:

(a) He or she falsely makes, completes, or alters a written instrument or;
(b) He or she possesses, utters, offers, disposes of, or puts off as true a written instrument which he or she knows to be forged.


"Defraud" is not defined in this statute, but typically involves three elements: a misrepresentation, someone who reasonably relies on that misrepresentation, and a harm that they suffer as a result. In this case, fraud probably doesn't result, since there is no harm, but that's a fact-specific question I'd expect to see argued in court.
To summarize:

Using an ID card that you know has been altered is a misdemeanor.
Altering it yourself is at least a gross misdemeanor.
If anyone suffers a loss as a result, it may amount to forgery, a class C felony.


An aside: in your question, you draw a distinction between a driver's license and a state ID card, but at least in Washington, the law doesn't. All of the law concerning the driver's license as a general ID applies equally to non-license ID cards.

Hm, does this law that you cite cover fictitious IDs used for movie production? The fact that that isn't exempted here makes me think this isn't the whole story?

@user541686 It doesn't appear to make an exception for them, nor would I expect there to be one. There's no reason a movie would need a reproduction-quality driver's license.

I hope nobody in Washington needs to hire a physical building penetration tester.

@Joshua: Fun fact, they'd probably have some "Company ID Card", and get in with that alone.
